# what does "TDFnlogn" mean in the context of time complexity?

Tags: algorithm

per [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity), the time complexity is

> the computational complexity that describes the amount of time it
> takes to run an algorithm.
>
> the time complexity is commonly expressed using big O notation,
> typically

[image]

when talk about time complexity, this [post](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2018/01/building-a-distributed-ml-pipeline-part1.html) use a term "TDFnlogn".

nlogn could be [image]

what does "TDFnlogn" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The time complexity of serially constructing a GBT model with T trees each of depth D is O(TDFnlogn), where F is the number of features and n is the number of training samples.

T is the number of trees. D is the depth of each tree. F is the number of features. n is the number of training samples. O(TDFnlogn) is proportional to the product of all of these and log n.